# Проблемы с стилизацией input checkbox

Tags: css

Мне нужно по клику на checkbox выбрать все чекбаксы (тут использовала jqury. Нет с этим поблем) + что бы зеленый квадрат исчезал и появлялся при клике на "Выбрать" либо на сам чекбокс. Вот код.Подскажите в чем проблема.

```js
$(".allTrue").click(function() {
       $(".allCheck").prop('checked', this.checked);
})
```

```css
.labelChose{
    position: relative;
}
  .allTrue {
    display: none;
}

.labelChose:before{
    content:"";
    width:20px;
    height: 20px;
    border:1px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
   margin-bottom:4px;
}
 .labelChose:after{
    content:"";
    width:10px;
    height: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #5cb85c;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-4" >
    <h5><label class="labelChose mt-2"> <input type="checkbox" class = "mr-2 allTrue"/>Выбрать</label></h5>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="allCheck">
    <span class="ml-3">ABank</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="allCheck">
    <span class="ml-3">ABank</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="allCheck">
    <span class="ml-3">ABank</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что псевдоэлементы (:before, :after) не являются частью DOM, а потому к ним нельзя обратиться с помощью jQuery. Стилизовать нужно сам label - придать ему вид чекбокса и менять фон. А псевдоэлемент можно подложить под текст, чтобы клик работал и на слове "Выбрать" (ну, или сделать декоративную галочку):

```js
$(".allTrue").click(function() {
     $('.allCheck').prop('checked', this.checked);
     $('label[for="allTrue"]').toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.labelChose{
  position: relative;
}
.allTrue {
  display: none;
}
label[for="allTrue"] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}
label[for="allTrue"].active {
  background-color: transparent;
}
label:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 7px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  z-index: -1;
}
label[for="allTrue"]:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-4" >
    <label class="labelChose mt-2" for="allTrue"></label> <span class="labelText">Выбрать</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="mr-2 allTrue" id="allTrue" />
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="allCheck">
    <span class="ml-3">ABank</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="allCheck">
    <span class="ml-3">ABank</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="allCheck">
    <span class="ml-3">ABank</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: humster_spb, спасибо вам. очень выручили